# How register all touch events in an activity?

Tags: android

How register with Log.i method all events in an activity?

For example:

> click on R.id.btn_checkout view
>
> longclick on R.id.calendar view

its possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want handle all the user interaction events against your activity, you can override `onUserInteraction` method.

> public void onUserInteraction ()
>
> Called whenever a key, touch, or trackball event
>   is dispatched to the activity. Implement this method if you wish to
>   know that the user has interacted with the device in some way while
>   your activity is running.

However, you can't figure out which event has been fired.

Comment: thank you, but i need the type of event and the view